# Spring boot camel Kafka

Tags: spring-camel

I have a Spring boot 2.25.1 application which is using Camel 2.25.1 with camel-kafka everything is working fine..
In my Kafka consumer, I have a need to add the feature to pause consumption on demand so I upgraded to camel 3.18.1 so I can use the pausable feature.
After upgrading to 3.18.1 I am getting error FileNotFound with class file TimeoutAwareAggregationStategy.class.

when I opened camel-core 3.18.1 jar this class does not exist which was available in came 2.25.1 version.

Please suggest.

I was expecting smoother upgrade from camel 2.25.1 to camel 3.18.1.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Camel upgrade guide for Camel 2.x to 3](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html), the `camel-core` was modularized and broken up into multiple jar files.  In that upgrade guide, they mention a lot of changes to Aggregation Strategies.  While I couldn't find a direct implementation of the `AggregationStrategy` interface called `TimeoutAwareAggregationStategy`, I can see that class exists in `camel-core` in [version 2.25.4](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.25.4/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy.html) and the `AggregationStrategy` interface is moved to `camel-api` in [version 3.0](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.0.0/org/apache/camel/AggregationStrategy.html).

> I was expecting smoother upgrade from camel 2.25.1 to camel 3.18.1

Normally, when upgrading a major version to a newer major version, there will be major changes that you have to account for.  These changes are almost always covered in the change list or upgrade guide.